# How I can find raster angle in ArcGIS

Tags: raster, arcgis-10.4, vector-grid, grids-graticules, angles

I have a raster layer in ArcGIS with specific extent. How can I be able to find the angle of this raster frame? Because I create fishnet but it is like a rectangular area and does not match to direction of each pixel of this raster layer. So, I need correct angle to rotate it.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify whether the raster has been georectified. If it hasn't the rotation is preserved in the world file. If it has, then the pixels are orthagonal to the coordinate system,  making this an artificial intelligence task. If the image is being rotated by on-the-fly reprojection, then it's likely a partial differential equation, with each pixel having a different value.

Comment: Do you know the extent by the four corners ?

Comment: yes i know the coorsinate system and four corners. But every images has a specific angle due to its satellite and scanning. This angle i want to know. Maybe for the general information of MODIS can i able?

Comment: Convert to single band, assign 1 to all, convert to polygon and use minimum bounding geometry. It has angle option

Comment: ohhh, perfect. Thanks a lot now i can understand what is its angle.